# Custom notification upon email arrival?

Tags: push-notification

I tried to implement a custom notification for *any* received email to Salesforce, but the notification doesn't appear, despite emails are being received and put in the chronology in the proper record (Contact).

(I've seen examples of custom notifications received for email within cases or leads and that's cool, but I need to notify the users upon any email received...)

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I did:

[image: Notification settings are ok]

(Notification settings are enabled)

1. Create a new custom notification:

[image: "New email" custom notification]

2. Create the process in Process Builder

[image: Process]

The process initiates when an "Email message" is created (only when created).
The criterion is "[EmailMessage].incoming = true
The action is as follows:

[image: Action after the criterion is true]

Note the Notification Recipient value is "Current User".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you received an answer on this yet, but you need to update who the Notification is assigned to. The running user on incoming emails is the Automated Case User, specified in Support Settings. You should instead use a formula or reference to call out the Case Owner